# Updated ubuntu 18.04 now get stuck in 5 dot screen after grub

Tags: boot, grub2

Updated ubuntu 18.04 now get stuck in 5 dot screen after grub. Lets me boot with safe mode but not with anything else. I have an Amd Ryzen cpu. Anyone else have this issue?

solved:
changed my display manager to lightdm and now it boots fine!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS was working fine, until I updated and rebooted and now I can't get beyond the 5 dot screen. Sometimes the screen goes to black, sometimes there's no more video signal.

I updated BIOS (Asus A320M-K), put memory speed back to default, removed SATA disks, no effect. I can get into recovery mode, I ran dpkg to repair broken packages but this didn't fix the issue either.

I also have an AMD Ryzen APU (2200G) and I'm using the AMDGPU or AMDGPU-PRO driver (I forget which).

EDIT: I fixed the issue by going into recovery mode, installing Mesa from the Padoka PPA and removing the AMDGPU driver. This might work for you if you also have the AMDGPU driver.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo amdgpu-pro-uninstall
```

Comment: found a solution changed my display manager to lightdm and it worked fine after that